# How to generate namespaces in XML docs with Db2?

Tags: sql, xml, db2

I want to generate the following xml doc in db2 and it has several namespaces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ecore:EPackage xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" 
xmlns:ComIbmCompute.msgnode="ComIbmCompute.msgnode" 
xmlns:ComIbmDatabase.msgnode="ComIbmDatabase.msgnode" 
xmlns:ComIbmWSInput.msgnode="ComIbmWSInput.msgnode" 
xmlns:ComIbmWSReply.msgnode="ComIbmWSReply.msgnode" 
xmlns:ecore="http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" 
xmlns:eflow="http://www.ibm.com/wbi/2005/eflow" 
xmlns:utility="http://www.ibm.com/wbi/2005/eflow_utility" 
nsURI="myflow/FIPRRCV.msgflow" nsPrefix="myflow_FIPRRCV.msgflow">
```

This does not work:

```
`SELECT XMLELEMENT(NAME "ecore:EPackage", 
XMLNAMESPACES('eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore'; AS "ecore")) as "result"
 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 WITH UR;`
```

How can I define multiple namespaces and use them in elements and attributes?

Comment: The above is not XML. Please extend your example to make it a valid XML fragment or document. You can generate XML documents in Db2 by using the XMLELEMENT, XMLATTRIBUTES and XMLNAMESPACES functions (and some more). What did you try...?

Comment: I can not make attribute "xmi:version" or "xmlns:xmi" by using the XMLELEMENT, XMLATTRIBUTES and XMLNAMESPACES functions. are u can ?  @data_henrik

Comment: show your SQL code and the result

Comment: SELECT XMLELEMENT(NAME "ecore:EPackage",
                XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore' AS "ecore"))    as "result"
FROM
    SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
WITH UR;        I CAN NOT ADD ANOTHER NAMESPACE AND XMI:VERSION

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function to use is called [XMLNAMESPACES](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0022190.html). The name suggests it is not a single, but multiple namespaceS are possible. :)

You can provide several namespace declarations in a comma-separated list. Only one namespace can be set as default namespace. Try something like this:

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT(NAME "ecore:EPackage",
         XMLNAMESPACES('eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore' AS "ecore", 
        'example.com/foobar' as "foobar")) as "result"
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

If you need to add attributes with a prefix in their name, then just pass that combined string as attribute name to [XMLATTRIBUTES](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0022184.html). The `xmi:version="2.0"` in your example is `"xmi:version"` as name with a value of `2.0`.

Comment: Thank you. Worked properly.
But what should I do to add the " XMI:VERSION"?

Comment: See the updated answer. It is really simple and the linked XMLATTRIBUTES has an similar example. RTFM.. :)

Comment: -Thank you very much @data_henrik
:)